# How to hide page from siteadmin in AEM?

Tags: servlets, aem, jcr, sling

I have a Sling Servlet with resourceType="this/is/a/test".

```
@SlingServlet(methods = { "GET" })
@Properties({ @Property(name = "service.pid", value = "com.test.TestServlet", propertyPrivate = false),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.resourceTypes", value = {"this/is/a/test"})})
public class TestServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {
```

I have an MSM structure with brand and locale in blueprint.

```
    SampleBlueprint
        Organization One
            en_US
               Home Page
               Contact US
               bin
                  test-servlet

   SampleLiveCopies
        Organization One
           America
              en_US
                 Home Page
                 Contact US
                 bin
                    test-servlet
              fr_US
                 Home Page
                 Contact US
                 bin
                    test-servlet
           Canada
              en_CA
                 Home Page
                 Contact US
                 bin
                    test-servlet
```

The test-servlet has sling:resourceType="this/is/a/test".

In the servlet I am utilizing the path to determine the response.
Ex: 
If path is /content/SampleLiveCopies/OrganizationOne/America/en_US/bin/test-servlet
I would return data which is America related in English language.

But as Page "bin/test-servlet" is visible in siteadmin, author has the control to edit it.

Hence I want to hide the bin/test-servlet page in siteadmin.

Comment: Do you need to create page for servlet under siteadmin? The servlet can [get path info](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/SlingHttpServletRequest.html#getRequestPathInfo()). Would you hit servlet via AJAX call from page say Home Page under en_US? Or the use case is different?

Comment: Yes. From home page, I would be requesting servlet by AJAX call. I have a servlet filter which recognises country, language from the URL. This provides the servlet ability to provide data. The problem of using path for servlet is that, the response will not get cashed in dispatcher, and would hit performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to hide page - you use property **hidden** with value **true** on **jcr:content** of the page. I bet, there would be similar approach. Give it a try.